# What is causing an InvalidSignatureException in Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, postman

I am attempting to send a request to a AWS endpoint in Postman and this is what I have done:
I have provided a URL and I have set the Authorization as AWS Signature and I have provided both the AccessKey and SecretKey.

I have inputted values for AWS Region (us-east-1) and I have attempted to enter execute-api and sqs for the Service Name input field but it is not returning a value. I have received a

```
<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'sqs'. </Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>
```

and

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

when I only provide a service name of 'sqs'

What is causing these errors and how do I fix them?

I am very new to Postman, AWS, APIs etc. so any information is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To use `AWS Signature` from postman for `SQS`, you need to supply the `Accesskey`, `Secret Key`, Service as `sqs` and your AWS region. You seem to be inputting these details correctly.  Provided that you filled all the details correctly, I suspect that you may not have sufficient privileges to access `SQS`. Therefore I suggest you test your configuration with elevated permissions such as `AmazonSQSFullAccess` and reduce the permissions once you get it working.

hope this helps.